# iOS multiple step information entry

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-experience

I am writing an iOS app that requires several pieces of information to be entered. I am trying to do this is the most iOS idiomatic way.

The user must:

- Select faulty PC from list
- Select fault type from list
- Enter fault detail text
- Enter shipping details

  - AC Adapter? - boolean
  - Shipping address - text view
  - Contact No - text box
  - Cost Centre - text box

My gut instinct was for a wizard with each major item on a separate view, with the shipping details as a form on a single view. However, I don't see any wizard data entry like that in Apple Apps.

What do people consider best? Multiple views as described, or a single table view with disclosure buttons for each major item to navigate to selection/entry screens. In that scenario, should the shipping details be a single table cell on the main page or multiple elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good "wizard data entry" example from Apple is the one you have to use every time iOs is updated. However it is inconvenient to fill any kind of a form this way, using a table view instead is a good way to show relatively simple forms.

If the order of filling in the form doesn't matter, use `Calendar` app `Add event` style, if it is important, add/remove sections as user enters/removes the data (similar to `Settings` > Wi-Fi).

Comment: I like the Calendar "Add Entry" style. Do you know how they created those grouped entry fields?

Comment: Got it. Grouped table fields.